# Why does std::uniform_real_distribution<double> produce NaN?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, random, std

I want to generate random numbers in the whole double range. Doing it like

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> doubleDist(std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(),
                                                  std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
```

produces IND / NaN, though. It took me a while to understand that this is according to [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution):

> Requires that `a ≤ b` and `b-a ≤ std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`

Clearly `std::numeric_limits<double>::max() - std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()` is larger than `::max`, since `:lowest` is  negative [(unlike `::min`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825815/will-min-to-max-uniform-real-distribution-produce-inf-inf-or-nan).

Why can't I generate numbers between lowest and max this way and what is the rationale behind?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52039103/3002139

Comment: Rational is probably ease of efficient implementation or sth like that. Someone would have to dig up the proposal.